# Is there a way to force a Dataflow job to stop after it is running for a long time

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

is there a way to force a DAtaflow job to kill itself if it is running longer than xxx hours?
Kind regards
Marco

Comment: **NOTE: We are in the process of implementing this for Batch Pipelines**. It is not yet available as a Dataflow flag, but it will be **within a month**.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the comment as an answer.

> We are in the process of implementing this for Batch Pipelines. It is not yet available as a Dataflow flag, but it will be within a month.

Answer (score 1):

We recently implemented this feature for Dataflow. You would do it by passing an extra experiment:

```
--experiments=max_workflow_runtime_walltime_seconds=300
```

Or whatever number of seconds.

---

Programatically this would be like so:

```java
String experimentValue = String.format(
    "max_workflow_runtime_walltime_seconds=%d",
    killAfterSeconds);
ExperimentalOptions.addExperiment(myOptions.as(ExperimentalOptions.class), experimentValue);
```

In Python:

```py
experiment_value = "max_workflow_runtime_walltime_seconds=%d" % timeout_secs
my_options.view_as(DebugOptions).add_experiment(experiment_value)
```

Comment: Hello I am using flex templates...can I still use that? Also which version  has that feature..I m on 2.38

Comment: yes, you can add that code / experiment option as a parameter to your template

Comment: Hi Pablo   in which version of dataflow is this option available? I am running 2.39.0. And